# Looped sound Hiccups

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio

I have a sound file I wish to loop like the engine of a vehicle.
The sound I have is 1 second long and it is a .wav file.
I'm quite certain the file is cut to be seamless,
it loops perfectly in Audacity.

I'm calling the sound with this code:

```
let playEngineSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("engine.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
let engineSoundLoop = SKAction.repeatActionForever(playEngineSound)
self.runAction(EngineSoundLoop, withKey: "engine sound")
```

I use "withKey" to be able to cancel it later.
The Sound comes out fine but there is a small but distinctive hiccup where the sound seems to be reloading or waiting for the other to stop completely before starting the new loop.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: After trying the AVAudioPlayer route, it plays flawlessly, someone knows anything about the behaviour? I still want to go purely SKAction if possible.

Comment: Code looks right. Maybe give it a try with a different sound file to verify it's not something with the file?

Comment: Good point, I'll do this next time I fire Xcode up.

Comment: Nope, no dice. On the other hand, I tried with AVAudioPlayer and it works flawlessly.. Wonder if there's anything in SKAction.playSoundFileNamed that creates the hiccup..

Comment: Where is this code placed ? In the viewDidLoad or in the update method ?

Comment: It was in the update method.